# Stop If and Else stetment on Counting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, if-statement

I want to create the page that show loading and than show the random number with time, but the problem is **when loading switch to random number, that random number change again to loading (looping)**.

here is my code :

```
<div class="spinner" id="box1">
  <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
  <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
</div>
<div class="suhu" style="display:none" id="box2">
 <span style="color: #E74C3C; font-size: 30px; text-align: center;">
    Suhu Anda : </span><span id="decimalgenerate" style="font-size: 30px;"></span><span style="font-size: 30px;">&#8451;<br/></span><span style="color: #E74C3C;"></span>
</div>
```

and here is the JS code :

```
setInterval(function thing() {

      var b1 = document.getElementById('box1');
      var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');

      if(b1['style'].display == 'none')break; {
        b1['style'].display = 'block';
        b2['style'].display = 'none';

      } else {
        b1['style'].display = 'none';
        b2['style'].display = 'block';

      }


    }, 7000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stop interval use `clearInterval`

```
var myTime = setInterval(function thing() {

      var b1 = document.getElementById('box1');
      var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');

      if(b1['style'].display == 'none')break; {
        b1['style'].display = 'block';
        b2['style'].display = 'none';

      } else {
        b1['style'].display = 'none';
        b2['style'].display = 'block';
      }
    }, 7000);
```

and where you want

```
clearInterval(myTime)
```

**Example:**

```
var myTime = setInterval(function thing() {

      var b1 = document.getElementById('box1');
      var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');

      if(b1['style'].display == 'none') {
        b1['style'].display = 'block';
        b2['style'].display = 'none';
        clearInterval(myTime);
      } else {
        b1['style'].display = 'none';
        b2['style'].display = 'block';
      }
    }, 7000);
```

Comment: hi Frank, thank you for help.
But my interval still runing.
    setInterval(function thing() {
  
  var b1 = document.getElementById('box1');
  var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');
  
  if(b1['style'].display == 'none'){
    b1['style'].display = 'block';
    b2['style'].display = 'none';
    
  } else {
    b1['style'].display = 'none';
    b2['style'].display = 'block';
    
  }

  
}, 7000);
clearInterval(myTime);

can you please tell me what is wrong for my code?
Thank youuu

Comment: Try the example. You must add "var myTime" before your setInterval and use clearInterval only where you want

Comment: I have remove break too. because is not important.